# Angular 8 add material chiplist with formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to add a list of chip list of Angular material with an Ng form. I am not able to add the new chip list on the click of the button and don't know how to display the value of array added in the new chip list chip list. Here is an example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-g1ggqr

```
   <button (click)="addNewChip()">Add new Chip</button><br><br>

  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList formArrayName="names">
  <mat-chip 
    *ngFor="let name of myForm.get('names').controls; let i=index;"
    [selectable]="selectable"
    [removable]="removable"
    (removed)="remove(myForm, i)">
    {{name.value}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
  <input placeholder="Names"
    [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
    [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
    [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
    (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, myForm)">
</mat-chip-list>
<mat-error>Atleast 1 name need to be added</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

component.ts file

```
export class ChipListValidationExample implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('chipList') chipList: MatChipList;
public myForm: FormGroup;

  // name chips
    visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
   readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];

// data
 data = {
  names: ['name1', 'name2']
  }

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  names: this.fb.array(this.data.names, this.validateArrayNotEmpty)
});
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.myForm.get('names').statusChanges.subscribe(
  status => this.chipList.errorState = status === 'INVALID'
);
}

 initName(name: string): FormControl {
return this.fb.control(name);
}

 validateArrayNotEmpty(c: FormControl) {
if (c.value && c.value.length === 0) {
  return {
    validateArrayNotEmpty: { valid: false }
  };
}
return null;
 }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent, form: FormGroup): void {
const input = event.input;
const value = event.value;

// Add name
         if ((value || '').trim()) {
  const control = <FormArray>form.get('names');
  control.push(this.initName(value.trim()));
  console.log(control);
}

// Reset the input value
if (input) {
  input.value = '';
}
  }

   remove(form, index) {
console.log(form);
form.get('names').removeAt(index);
 }

  addNewChip(){
  console.log("Yse")
   this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  names: this.fb.array(this.data.names, this.validateArrayNotEmpty)
   });
   }
```

}

Comment: you are trying to add a chip to chip list or add a chip list to existing form??

Comment: You need to use controlValueAccessor that defines an interface that acts as a bridge between the Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM. https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: tring to add a chip list in existing form. On click of the add button, Everytime It should display one more input form where I can add the chips..

Comment: @Subham Please check the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

- Modified addChip,removeChip methods to work on current Chiplist in the FormArray by passing the formControl to the methods.
- Modified data to accept a name and initial set of values
- Modified addNewChipList method to add a formControl to the existing forArray

```
 <button (click)="addNewChipList()">Add new Chip</button><br><br>

<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<ng-container formArrayName="names"
  *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('names').controls; let i = index;">
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList >
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let val of item.value.val"
        [selectable]="selectable"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="removeChip(item, val)">
        {{val}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input [placeholder]="item.value.name"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addChip($event, item)">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-error>Atleast 1 name need to be added</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
</form>
```

```
// data
data = {
  names: [this.initName('name1'), this.initName('name2', ['A', 'B'])]
}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    names: this.fb.array(this.data.names, this.validateArrayNotEmpty)
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('names').statusChanges.subscribe(
    status => this.chipList.errorState = status === 'INVALID'
  );
}

initName(name: string, val: string[]=[]): FormControl {
  return this.fb.control({ name, val });
}

validateArrayNotEmpty(c: FormControl) {
  if (c.value && c.value.length === 0) {
    return {
      validateArrayNotEmpty: { valid: false }
    };
  }
  return null;
}

addChip(event: MatChipInputEvent, ctrl: FormControl): void {
  const input = event.input;
  const value = event.value;

  // Add name
  if ((value || '').trim()) {
    const control = ctrl;
    control.value.val.push(value.trim());
    console.log(control.value);
  }

  // Reset the input value
  if (input) {
    input.value = '';
  }
}

removeChip(ctrl, val) {
  const idx = ctrl.value.val.findIndex(item => item === val);
  ctrl.value.val.splice(idx, 1);
}

addNewChipList() {
  const items = this.myForm.get('names') as FormArray;
  items.push(this.initName(`name${items.length + 1}`));
}
```

Updated Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-fzjlnm